# Adsense API - list specific product ads

Tags: ads, adsense

Can I use adsense API to search for a specific list of products?

Let's say I'm building a page that, based on user's inputs, shows a list of products from online stores.

For exemple, the form filled by the user give's me an array of books:

```
['Harry Potter and the...', 'Lord of the rings and the ...', 'Hamlet]
```

Then I make a query to an API that sends me those exact book ads on amazon, ebay, etc.
Let's say

```
[
    {
        "book": "Harry Potter...",
        "author": "J.K",
        "stores": [
            { 
                "store": "Amazon",
                "url": "http://www.amazon.com/harry-potter-and-the",
                "price": "10 USD",
                "pictures": ["amazon.com/harrypotter-cover.jpg", "amazon.com...jpg"]
            },
            { 
                "store": "Ebay",
                "url": "http://www.ebay.com/harry-potter-and-the",
                "price": "20 USD",
                "pictures": ["ebay.com...jpg"]

            }  
        ]
    },
    {
        "book": "Lord of the rings and ...",
        ...
    }

]
```